# Pubnub iOS: How to change Pubnub delegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, pubnub

I have 2 classes. The first class allows you to tap a button to subscribe to a channel.
The first class is instantiated like so:

```
pubnub = [[CEPubnub alloc] initWithPublishKey:@"demo" subscribeKey:@"demo" secretKey:@"demo" cipherKey:nil useSSL:NO];
[pubnub setDelegate:self];
```

In my second class, everything is great until I try to publish a message from the Pubnub developer console. When I do publish a message from the developer console I get output of "Received 1 messages from PubNub channel {name}. But the optional Pubnub delegate method I am using is getting called but not printing out my NSLOG.

I rooted the issue with the delegate being set to my first class. But I am new to iPhone/objective C and could use some help in setting the delegate of my Pubnub object to the second class.

I have tried to set the delegate to nil whenever the first class: viewWillDisappear and then set delegate again in the second class: viewWillAppear but no luck =(  Am I doing something wrong?

Sorry if this is confusing, im still learning. :)

Comment: I solved this by creating a single class that wrapped the pubnub object and accessed it through there.

Comment: Hi ,Can you post here your solution !

Comment: Could you put up more code? There's no way to know if what you are describing is what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to keep it simple. Creating custom classes is just going to make it more difficult to get started. I suggest just follow the simple tutorial here (new SDK since this question was posted with streamlined API).

https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/pubnub-objective-c-sdk-v4